# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value' ' to data type int in Xml Parsing

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

```
DECLARE @xml xml ='<Root><Child><Number>
80</Number></Child></Root>'

SELECT  c.value('(./Number)[1]', 'int') AS Number  FROM @xml.nodes('Root/Child') T(c)
```

I am getting the xml  from the file, so if the value of the node ( here it is 80 )is in the new line ,on selecting the xml using the above query I got an error like:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '
>   80' to data type int.

But If the xml is declare in the same line like `DECLARE @xml xml ='<Root><Child><Number>80</Number></Child></Root>'`

It will work fine. How could I solve this issue . Anybody please  help me to proceed

Comment: I've tried to edit the question to get the formatting to work better. I know from your question that layout is quite important, so I hope I've not screwed it up. I've also added a SQL Server tag, since I am 99.9999% sure that that's what you're working with. If either of these are wrong, please re-edit your question and get the formatting corrected and/or re-tag with an appropriate technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`number`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191139.aspx) function:

```
DECLARE @xml xml ='<Root><Child><Number>
80</Number></Child></Root>'

SELECT  c.value('number((./Number)[1])', 'int') AS Number
FROM @xml.nodes('Root/Child') T(c)
```

Comment: +1. Another way would be to cast as int in the XQuery expression `c.value('(./Number)[1] cast as xs:int?', 'int')`